# `std::function` template argument deduction/substitution failed

Tags: templates, c++11, implicit-conversion

This is essentially what I am trying to do, but it fails:

```
#include <functional>


class MyClass
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    MyClass(const std::function<void (const T& )>& )
    {
    }

};

void function(const int& i)
{

}

int main()
{
    MyClass t( &function );
    // ^ main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
    //   main.cpp:20:26: error: no matching function for call to
    //   ‘MyClass::MyClass(void (*)(const int&))’
    //        MyClass t( &function );
    //                             ^
    //   main.cpp:7:5: note: candidate: 
    //   template<class T> MyClass::MyClass(const std::function<void(const T&)>&)
    //        MyClass(const std::function<void (const T& )>& )
    //        ^
    //   main.cpp:7:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
    //   main.cpp:20:26: note:   mismatched types 
    //   ‘const std::function<void(const T&)>’ and ‘void (*)(const int&)’
    //        MyClass t( &function );
    //                             ^
    //   main.cpp:4:7: note: candidate: constexpr MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass&)
    //    class MyClass
    //          ^
    //   main.cpp:4:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 
    //   ‘void (*)(const int&)’ to ‘const MyClass&’
    //   main.cpp:4:7: note: candidate: constexpr MyClass::MyClass(MyClass&&)
    //   main.cpp:4:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 
    //   ‘void (*)(const int&)’ to ‘MyClass&&’


}
```

The plain function will not convert into `std::function`, instead the compiler tries the copy or move constructor, which obviously fails. I have no idea why this happens. Is there a nice way to make line 20 working?

**EDIT:** Constructor of MyClass `public`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the problem:
the compiler expects some `std::function` as argument in order to deduce the type `T`. here, you give the compiler impossible case: first implicitly convert `&function` into `std::function<void(const int&)>` then deduce `T` as `int`. the compiler doesn't know how to do it. it cant both implicitly convert pointer to funciton int std::function and deduce the template type.

second of all, the constructor is private.

now , how do we solve it?

option 1:
wrap the function pointer in std::function:

```
MyClass t( std::function<void(const int&)>(function) );
```

option 2:
overload the constructor as one who gets pointer to function

```
template <class T> 
    MyClass(void (*p)(const T& ))
    {
    }
```

option 3:
overload the constructor to some callable:

```
template <class Callable>
Myclass (Callable c){}
```

Comment: Sorry that the constructor was private, that was not my intention. But the problem is the same.

OK. I had removed the implementation details in order to make a simple example. But the type `T` had to be known inside the constructor, so option 3 can not be used. And option 1 is not as line 20. Option 2 works well. I thought I could go with just one Ctor, but you explained how the compiler was reasoning. Thank you!